# Split long words into equal-length pieces

Tags: javascript, string, split

How can I use JavaScript to split extremely long words? I am not looking for a CSS solution like `word-break: break-all`. The goal is to insert spaces in long words to break them into smaller pieces. The solution should be as fast as possible, since it will be called thousands of times in a few seconds.

Example how the solution should work:

```
splitString("This is an exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxample string.");
=> This is an exxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxample string.

splitString("AnotherExammmmmmmmmmmpleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
=> AnotherExammmmmm mmmmmpleeeeeee eeeeeeeeee
```

Any words that are too long are split with a space character.

It would be even better if the resulting pieces were of roughly equal length.

Comment: You need to clarify what you want. Each line exactly the same length? 'Too long' is meaningless without context

Comment: To be clear, you only want to split *words* longer than a certain length and care nothing about the total or line length?

Comment: I'm working on an answer for this, will take some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for performance, I compared a **regex** approach:

```
function splitString(str, length) {
  var regex = new RegExp("/(\w{" + length + "})(?=\w)/g");
  return str.replace(regex, "$1 ");
}
```

with this relatively simple **handmade** solution:

```
function splitString(str, length) {
    var words = str.split(" ");
    for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        var l = words[j].length;
        if (l > length) {
            var result = [], i = 0;
            while (i < l) {
                result.push(words[j].substr(i, length))
                i += length;
            }
            words[j] = result.join(" ");
        }
    }
    return words.join(" ");
}
```

[JsPerf](http://jsperf.com/splitwords) says that the regex version is roughly 8% faster on my machine (Mac Opera16). As this is also more concise, I would go for it.

Comment: heh overwriting words[j] with the join is much better than my approach with the splice. Nice one.

Comment: Also, on a performance note using Chrome (win 8 64 bit) the regex is actually slower than the handmade.

Comment: If `length` is fixed or only takes a few values, of course you'd want to compile the regex once instead of on each invocation. Assuming you use the function more than once, this would improve the performance.

Comment: Replace \w with \S and use `var regex = new RegExp("/(\S{" + length + "})(?=\S)/g");` to cover anything besides whitespace. JS RegEx reference [link] (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 1):

While this does nothing to ensure that the pieces are of equal length, it will ensure no word in your string is longer than 40 characters.

```
'This is an exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxample string.'
    .replace(/(\w{40})(?=\w)/g, '$1 ');

>> 'This is an exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xample string.'
```

A "word" is defined here as a consecutive string of letters, numbers, and underscores. If you wish to apply a different definition of "word" (e.g., if your "words" can contain Unicode characters), you will need to swap `\w` for the character class of your choice.

Comment: `\w` matches letters, numbers, and the underscore (equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`). It will leave Unicode characters as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/czBZz/

```
function splitString(value) {
    var tooLongDeterminer = 12;
    var words = value.split(' ');
    for (var i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (words[i].length > tooLongDeterminer) {
            var split = words[i];
            var tempArray = new Array();
            while (split != '') {
                var word = splitWord(split, tooLongDeterminer);
                tempArray.push(word);
                split = split.replace(word, '');
            }

            words.splice(i, 1, tempArray.join(' '));
        }
    }
    return words.join(' ');

}

function splitWord(word, length) {
    return word.substring(0, length);
}

console.log(splitString("This is an exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxample string."));

console.log(splitString("AnotherExammmmmmmmmmmpleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"));
```

Note: this is recursive (and only tested on chrome) so may or may not suit your purposes but the output from the above console.logs are as follows:

`AnotherExamm mmmmmmmmmple eeeeeeeeeeee eeee`

`This is an exxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxample string.`

Hope this helps and thanks for the challenge :)